# how to initialise a public property

Tags: c#-3.0

now how to initialise a value for it.
I know that i can initialise a property as

```
private int _formId=1;

public int FromID 
{
   get
      {
          return _formId;
      }
   set
      {
          _formId= value;
      }
```

But if i create a property as

```
public int FromID { get; set; }
```

How can i initialise its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize it in the constructor of your class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        FromID = 1;
    }

    public int FromID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is there any difference in initialising properties in both the ways?

Answer (score 0):

> public int FromID { get; set; }

is a short hand for the first piece of code.
If you need to set a value use the first piece of code

Comment: is there any difference in initialising properties in both the ways?